# Parse Phone Number into component parts

Tags: parsing, phone-number

I need a well tested Regular Expression (.net style preferred), or some other simple bit of code that will parse a USA/CA phone number into component parts, so:

- 3035551234122
- 1-303-555-1234x122
- (303)555-1234-122
- 1 (303) 555 -1234-122

etc...

all parse into:

- AreaCode: 303
- Exchange: 555
- Suffix: 1234
- Extension: 122

Answer (score 21):

None of the answers given so far was robust enough for me, so I continued looking for something better, and I found it:

[Google's library for dealing with phone numbers](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

I hope it is also useful for you.

Comment: +1 for good resource, -0.1 for not .NET (which was only a preference)
Sadly we're doing integer math and it gets truncated to 0.

Comment: Can you show how this library was able to parse a phone number into its constituent parts? As the OP mentioned, into Area Code, Exchange, and Suffix?

Answer (score 3):

This is the one I use:

```
^(?:(?:[\+]?(?<CountryCode>[\d]{1,3}(?:[ ]+|[\-.])))?[(]?(?<AreaCode>[\d]{3})[\-/)]?(?:[ ]+)?)?(?<Number>[a-zA-Z2-9][a-zA-Z0-9 \-.]{6,})(?:(?:[ ]+|[xX]|(i:ext[\.]?)){1,2}(?<Ext>[\d]{1,5}))?$
```

I got it from [RegexLib](http://regexlib.com) I believe.

Comment: That's horrible. My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: javascript doesn't have named groups, and it wasn't capturing the extension until I put a ? after the {6,} range.  Wound up with: `/^(?:(?:[\+]?(\d{1,3}(?:\s+|[\-\.])))?[\(]?(\d{3})[\-\/)]?(?:\s+)?)?([a-zA-Z2-9][a-zA-Z0-9 \-\.]{6,}?)(?:(?:\s+|[xX]|(?:[Ee]xt[\.]?)){1,2}(\d{1,5}))?$/`

Answer (score 1):

Strip out anything that's not a digit first.  Then all your examples reduce to:

`/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d*)$/`

To support all country codes is a little more complicated, but the same general rule applies.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works exactly as you want with your examples:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\(?(?<AreaCode>[0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?(?<Exchange>[0-9]{3})[-. ]*?(?<Suffix>[0-9]{4})[-. x]?(?<Extension>[0-9]{3})");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match("1 (303) 555 -1234-122");

// Now you have the results in groups 
matchResult.Groups["AreaCode"];
matchResult.Groups["Exchange"];
matchResult.Groups["Suffix"];
matchResult.Groups["Extension"];
```

Comment: Adding  +1 into consideration `new Regex(@"1?\(?(?<AreaCode>[0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?(?<Exchange>[0-9]{3})[-. ]*?(?<Suffix>[0-9]{4})[-. x]?(?<Extension>[0-9]{3})");` e.g. `+13035551234122`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a well-written library used with GeoIP for instance:

http://highway.to/geoip/numberparser.inc

Answer (score 0):

here's a method easier on the eyes provided by the Z Directory (vettrasoft.com),
geared towards American phone numbers:

```
string_o s2, s1 = "888/872.7676";
z_fix_phone_number (s1, s2);
cout << s2.print();      // prints "+1 (888) 872-7676"
phone_number_o pho = s2;
pho.store_save();
```

the last line stores the number to database table "phone_number".
column values: country_code = "1", area_code = "888", exchange = "872",
etc.