# How to parse a telephone number from calendar Event.Description to textbox in android?

Tags: android

I am using a calendar and the event description consists of some telephone numbers how can i parse the numbers and put it in the textbox.Is there any API for that in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Google's libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).

I haven't used myself, but it's one of my "I'll need that one day" links.

Related question: [Parse Phone Number into component parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227473/parse-phone-number-into-component-parts).